# High resolution process monitoring / logging on Linux

Tags: linux, performance, linux-kernel, monitoring

I've started to write some software to perform high resolution monitoring of process interaction with hardware on a Linux system. My aim is to log counters etc, sampling many times a second, on **a single process**. 
I'm interested in the hardware metrics like IO, CPU, Paging etc. With this granularity I should be able to get some insight into how a process is running, where it is bound, and how it performs its workload or responds to requests.

Is there any software which does this already?
Is getting the data from */proc/pid/file* ok, or should I go and read up on 'linux/proc_fs' to get faster access to the data? (or is there something even quicker again)

Comment: have you checked `strace` ?

Comment: strace is great for calls between app -> kernel.  I'm really interested in how the app interacts with all aspects of the hardware. I don't think I could get paging stats out of strace? could I?

Comment: The app needs the kernel to interact with the hardware. Check for ioctl calls in strace's output. Or are you looking how the kernel interacts with the hardware?

Comment: I'm looking to log the counters which the kernel keeps in great detail about a process in its procfs. To tie system calls to movements in these counters would be very valuable, but that's not my first goal (I am thinking about adding this later). I'm finding it really hard to believe that there is not software that does this already.

Comment: You can use `systemtab` to hook really deep into the kernel .. I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for

Comment: systemtap looks like it could handle most of what I'm after. I'll be digging into that some more. /proc still looks like a great way to log detailed per process statistics I'll weigh them up

Comment: Ok, would appreciate if you post your results once.

Comment: Another tools is perf. https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Thanks Alan - Perf looks like its got much of the information I wanted

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Grafana (http://grafana.org/) in combination with InfluxDB (https://influxdb.com/)
It's free, it's easy and it is open source.

I wrote a Powershell script which does plus minus what you are describing for Windows perfmon counters => http://outsideit.net/naf-windows-perfmon-to-influxdb/

You should be able to use collectd for Linux servers though.